# I get an error when build my Angular Application

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, nginx, npm

I have install Angular 8 and I get the next error when I build my app in GitHub Actions.

```
ERROR in main-es2015.e1115c7c82627ce27910.js from Terser
TypeError: Cannot read property 'variables' of undefined
    at /app/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1:209686
    at /app/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1:211321
    at AST_Call.optimize (/app/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1:137138)
    at ri.before (/app/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1:136915)
    at AST_Call.transform (/app/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1:84111)
    at /app/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1:84275
    at l (/app/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1:931)
    at e (/app/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1:1251)
    at Nn (/app/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1:84249)
    at /app/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1:86559
    at ri.before (/app/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1:136887)
    at AST_Sequence.transform (/app/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1:84111)
    at /app/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1:84817
    at ri.before (/app/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1:136887)
    at AST_SimpleStatement.transform (/app/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1:84111)
    at /app/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1:84275
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
```

My dockerfile is

```
FROM node:11.15.0-alpine as build-step
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build -- --configuration=production

FROM nginx:alpine-perl as prod-stage
COPY docker/nginx/default.conf.template /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.template

RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
COPY --from=build-step app/dist/AppName /usr/share/nginx/html

## startup.sh script is launched at container run
CMD /bin/sh -c "envsubst '\$PORT' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf" && nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

I don't understand where is the problem, can be cause by install ng-spinner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem was that I install last version of ngx-spinner (v9.0.1) but I'm using Angular 8 and I needed ngx-spinner (v8.0.1)

I hope this solution help another one person